# Setup local machine/container as edge node for submitting spark applications on remote cluster

Tags: apache-spark, containers, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to setup my container as edge node for running spark applications on my dev cluster, where spark/hadoop(Spark 2.2.0) is installed.

This is the stragegy that I followed, so far, how ever I am getting errors while submitting applications:

1. Installed spark on my container using compressed file spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz
2. Uncompressed the spark tar file
3. Installed java 8 on container
4. Copied core-site.xml,hdfs-site.xml,yarn-site.xml from my dev cluster and copied it to conf folder inside container local spark conf folder.
5. Setup SPARK_HOME on container and point path to $SPARK_HOME/bin
6. Setup HADOOP_CONF_DIR and point it $SPARK_HOME/conf, where I copied hdfs-site.xml and other xml files.

I also tried to set SPARK_LOCAL_IP to dev cluster edge machine, where we normally submit spark-submit.

This is How I submit spark-submit on my container:

`spark-submit --master yarn  --queue stark --total-executor-cores 4 --executor-cores 2 --executor-memory 10g --driver-memory 10g --name Test_Spark --class ca.ix.hubble.insights.runner.JobRunnerOptimized hdfs://novus-nameservice/tmp/airflowtest/insights.jar`

If I do that, I am getting following errors:

````
java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: Service 'sparkDriver' failed after 16 retries (on a random free port)! Consider explicitly setting the appropriate binding address for the service 'sparkDriver' (for example spark.driver.bindAddress for SparkDriver) to the correct binding address.
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:461)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:453)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:222)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:127)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:501)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1218)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:496)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:481)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:965)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:210)
        at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:353)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:399)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:446)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)```
````

Answer (score 0):

Btw I figured it out by myself,
Here is how I setup my local machine as edge node:

1. Copied spark2,hadoop directory from remote server where hadoop is installed to my local at /tmp/.
   You can also installed hadoop and spark locally and then replace core-site.xml,hdfs-site.xml,yarn-site.xml from your cluster to local default files. You might also want to bring spark-env.sh for spark.
2. Created HADOOP_HOME environment variable and pointed to local
   e.g. `export HADOOP_HOME=/tmp/hadoop`
3. Created SPARK_HOME environment variable and pointed to local
   e.g. `export SPARK_HOME=/tmp/spark2`
4. Created HADOOP_CONF_DIR and pointed to local at
   e.g. `export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/tmp/hadoop/conf`
5. Installed java and set JAVA_HOME environment variable
6. Add all the environment variable bin directories to PATH
   e.g. `export PATH=$PATH:${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${SPARK_HOME}/bin:${HADOOP_HOME}/bin`
7. Please make sure that all the remote servers hostname and ip addresses entries are there in your local hosts file at /etc/hosts
8. In order to submit spark-submit application to your remote hadoop server from your local use deployment mode as cluster
   e.g.

````
spark-submit --master yarn  --queue default --deploy-mode cluster --total-executor-cores 4 --executor-cores 2 --executor-memory 10g --driver-memory 10g --name Test_Spark --class ca.test.TestClass hdfs://hostname/tmp/test.jar```
````